Таймер обратного отсчёта после функции
У меня есть функция генерации рандомного числа, и анимация для него(от 0 до генерируемого числа) как мне сделать так, что бы перед генерацией нового числа на его месте появлялся таймер обратного отсчёта(для примера от 30 секунд до 0, далее код генерации числа, после чего снова от 30 до 0 и так далее) Я пытался реализовать это через setTimeout, но толкового ничего не вышло, надеюсь на вашу помощь
Вот сам код:
const oneStepTime = 100;
const disp = document.getElementById("out");

function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
  let acc = 0;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let step = 0.01;
    if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
      acc += step;
    } else {
      acc = maxNumber
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    disp.innerText = acc.toFixed(2);
  }, oneStepTime);
}
function run(min, max) {
  const waitTime = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 10000;
  console.log('Надо подождать', waitTime);
  setTimeout(() => {
    randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
    run(min, max);
  }, waitTime);
}

function Random() {
  const max = 5;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * max * 100) / 100;
}

randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
run(3, 10);


Попробуйте вот так что ли:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Random Number Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="out">0.00</div>
  <div id="timer"></div>

  <script>
    const oneStepTime = 100;
    const disp = document.getElementById("out");
    const timerDisp = document.getElementById("timer");

    function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
      let acc = 0;
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        let step = 0.01;
        if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
          acc += step;
        } else {
          acc = maxNumber;
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        disp.innerText = acc.toFixed(2);
      }, oneStepTime);
    }

    function run(min, max) {
      const waitTime = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 10000;
      console.log('Надо подождать', waitTime);

      // Display countdown timer
      let count = 30;
      const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timerDisp.innerText = count;
        count--;
        if (count < 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownInterval);
          timerDisp.innerText = '';
          randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
          run(min, max);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    function Random() {
      const max = 5;
      return Math.round(Math.random() * max * 100) / 100;
    }

    randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
    run(3, 10);
  </script>
</body>
</html>


Уберите вызов randomFloat в конце скрипта, оставьте только run. Из функции run надо убрать запуск себя же, когда count < 0 и перенести его в randomFloat и вотнуть после clearInterval. После этого можно увидеть, что в run() переменные уже не нужны и можно их убрать, как и переменную waitTime.

Возможно ли сделать так, что бы при установке условных 5 секунд число не перезапускало заново, а после завершения таймера ожидало, пока число полностью накрутит до окончательного значения, и уже после этого запускало сам таймер(Тобиш сначала таймер 5с, далее число, и уже после завершения числа(его остановки и паузы примерно секунд 4-5) начинался заново отсчёт 5 секунд и так до бесконечности))?

@user588774 Если выполните действия из моего комментария, то вроде как получите ожидаемый результат

Так как я совсем 0, то хотелось бы ещё спросить, возможно ли туда внедрить, что бы минимальное число было для примера 2.00, и от него шел отсчёт? так же будет ли возможность вывести данный код сразу на 2 #out, #out1, #out2, тобиш на 2 рядом стоящие панели одновременно, спасибо за ответ!

@user588774, да, можно. Я позже изменю ответ
